# UIInterpolatingMotionEffect swift XCode

Tags: swift

I am trying to define a motion effect with the code in the new language Swift

```
var axis_x_motion: UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect( "center.x", UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis)
```

but Xcode returns the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis'"

Also I am trying with

```
var axis_x_motion: UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect( "center.x", TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
```

but Xcode then returns the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'TiltAlongHorizontalAxis'"

Answer (score 3):

Before I go in to an explanation, lets take a look at the corrected code

```
var axisXMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
```

As a quick bit of information, the convention of the Swift language is to be using CamelCase rather than snake_case.

Right, on to what these changes mean. Swift uses a concept of named arguments and will require that you use those argument names in most situations. For instance if we take a look at the initialiser for `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` we can see that it requires two arguments,

```
init(keyPath: String!, type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType)
```

These arguments are named `keyPath` and `type`, so we need to specify them in our call.

As for the unrecognised identifiers, this comes down to how Swift identifies enumeration values. In C we were able to provide the name of the identifier in such a way that we could say `UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis`. However in Swift we need to provide both the name and the case of the enumeration, like so:

`UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis`

But as you can see I didn't specify the `UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType` portion of that previously. This is because Swift uses *Type Inference*. The compiler can see that the argument is expected to be of type `UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType` and thus allows us to omit it and just specify `.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis`.

You can also make use of this Type Inference when creating your variable. The compiler knows that the initialiser of `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` will return an object of type `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` and so can infer the required type, thus allowing you to omit it.

I hope this helps explain some of this, and if you need any more help or explanation, just ask!

Comment: Thanks. my final code is  var axis_x_motion: UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis) and  var axis_x_motion: UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type:.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
also working

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses a new dot-syntax for accessing enum values. You must combine the enum name (UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType) and the particular member value you wish to access (TiltAlongVerticalAxis) like this:

```
var axis_x_motion: UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect("center.x", UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
```